# flash cs4 file reference. Event.COMPLETE not called on a MAC,

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, filereference

I am working with a fileReference, however I'm having issues running on Safari on a MAC...

**EDIT:**
The below example also doesnt work on Safari on a MAC...

http://www.permadi.com/blog/2010/06/flash-as3-using-filereference-to-load-files-example-for-flash-cs4-and-above/

The workflow on a PC runs as such:

1. Create file reference
2. attach `addEventListener` for `Event.SELECT` and `Event.COMPLETE`
3. call the `browse()` method

On a PC, `Event.SELECT` is fired when a file has been selected.
`Event.COMPLETE` is fired when the file data is available to flash.  If I select an 500 MB file, it takes a few seconds before `Event.COMPLETE` is fired.  If I attempt to access the file data properties (such as reading the data stream) before `Event.COMPLETE` is fired, I receive null reference errors...

So far so good...

However, on a MAC (specifically Safari, not tested other browsers), the `Event.COMPLETE` is not fired.

I have checked the Adobe docs, which say `Event.COMPLETE` is fired when the upload is completed.  So *why* does it get fired on windows when the `fileReference` has parsed the file, but the upload method has not yet been called...

Can anyone help?

Here's snippets of the code I am working on:

```
public function browseFile(target:Object):void 
{
   var imagesFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Allowed files", "*.jpg;*.bmp;*.flv;");
   fileReference.browse([imagesFilter]);
   fileReference.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelect); 
   fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileSelectComplete); 
}  


private function fileSelect(event:Event):void 
{    
   // update label - IMPORTANT for large files as there's a delay while flash parses file, before control is handed back to this script...
   setStatusLabel("...loading file");

   var fileReference:FileReference = event.target as FileReference; 

   fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileSelectComplete); 


   // load the file into the fileReference object
   fileReference.load();  

} 


  // Called when upload file has been processed by flash (a few secs for large files, or fileRef.data is null...)
private function fileSelectComplete(event:Event):void 
{
   var fileReference:FileReference=event.target as FileReference; 

   trace("ready to do things - but not fired on Safari on a MAC ");
}
```

Comment: I can confirm the problem, but I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

definitely a bug of sdk 3.4 I have a work round here

```
        var fr:FileReference = e.currentTarget as FileReference;
        fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onModelDone);
        fr.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
//            trace("loading...");
        setTimeout(function():void {fr.load()}, 1);  // put it here for delay
```

I tried it on sdk3.9 it still the same, so I filed a bug here:
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3687113

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have gotten it working, using DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA instead of Event.COMPLETE.

```
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
fileRef.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, onUploadComplete);

function onFileSelected(event:Event):void {
    statusBar.text = "File upload started";
    fileRef.upload(FILE_UPLOAD_URL);
};

function onUploadComplete(event:Event):void {
    statusBar.text = "File upload completed";
};
```

Comment: Fantastic!  I'll run the change and get back to you -sorry it's been so long!